# java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "null" .. can't figure out why

Tags: java, android

I keep getting this error even though I'm following someone on Youtube and copying his code. He doesn't get the error, but I do.

The following code is in class `Cart`

```
  // Calculating the total price

   int total = 0 ;
    for(Order order:cart)
        total += (Integer.parseInt(order.getPrice())) * (Integer.parseInt(order.getQuantity()));


    Locale locale = new Locale("en" , "US"  );
    NumberFormat fmt = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(locale);

    txtTotalPrice.setText(fmt.format(total));
```

The following code is in class `CartAdapter`

```
    int price = (Integer.parseInt(listData.get(position).getPrice()))
            *(Integer.parseInt(listData.get(position).getQuantity()));
    holder.txt_price.setText(fmt.format(price));

    holder.txt_cart_name.setText(listData.get(position).getProductName());
```

Comment: I think you need to show more code and also show the full error

Answer (score 2):

I`order.getPrice()` may be `null` .And `order.getQuantity()` may be `null`

If one of them or both of them are null,it will cause `NumberFormatException`

So you can do like this .

If you want use them .

```
total += (Integer.parseInt(TextUtils.isEmpty(order.getPrice()) ? "0" : order.getPrice())) * (Integer.parseInt(TextUtils.isEmpty(order.getQuantity()) ? "0" : order.getQuantity()));
```

And

```
int price = (Integer.parseInt(TextUtils.isEmpty(listData.get(position).getPrice()) ? "0" : listData.get(position).getPrice()))
            *(TextUtils.isEmpty(listData.get(position).getQuantity()) ? "0" : listData.get(position).getQuantity());
```

**Note**

You can do like this , if your response is null ,you can return a default value .It will not cause `NumberFormatException` .

```
TextUtils.isEmpty(response) ? "0" : response;
```